# php trim away undesired texts

Tags: php

I have the following data in mysql database which is an iframe from u-tube:-

```
`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Om2fabTIKE4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`
```

Nevertheless, in the php codes, a present phase is present for the above iframe, in which I just need Om2fabTIKE4 as the variable to be filled in.

```
I would like to ask, is there any way that I can trim away
```

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/`

and

`frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: sounds like a job for preg_replace(), preg_match()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove the text

Comment: it works! However, I realize, when the u-tube iframe is width="420" height="315", the str_replace can no longer works. Would there be another expression that can recognize the length of the string, or recognize "<iframe" to "embed/"??

Comment: a simple method is to run it twice once for `560` and another for `420` check out regular expression if you want to do it in a single line. Use [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to get the length of a string. you can also [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string with a delimiter of `embed/`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$html = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/Om2fabTIKE4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();                                                                           
$dom->loadHTML($html);                                                                              
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('iframe');                                                       
foreach ($tags as $tag)                                                                             
  $link = explode('/',parse_url($tag->getAttribute('src'),PHP_URL_PATH));                           
var_dump($link[2]);
```

You can learn more about the [DOMDocument class here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).